# HTML JS , Append a new div to html body

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, cpanel

i wanna add a new  div,created with js, to the html file.I use cpanel as storage.

html

```
<div class="row onerow"></div>
```

js

```
 $( "<div></div>" ).appendTo( ".onerow").addClass("col")
```

I wanna save that new div i just created on the html body.Right now the div is deleted on page refresh.

*Full story: I have to create a website that contains a one row gallery.I wanna create a script where the admin can upload a photo and that photo will join the row as a new col.Upload is ready,but now i have to figure how to save the col to html body.Thank you for your time!*

Comment: `onerow` is not a class in your example. It's an attribute - because of the missing quotes.

Comment: the syntax for class is `class="className"` . Add the quotes

Comment: Yes,sorry, *edited*

Comment: JavaScript, at least in the form of web browser scripts, is not how you're going to be able to go about making a permanent change to the website. You'll need to look into server-side programming where the server-side code can save submitted data and alter the HTML that is served to each visitor on subsequent visits.

Comment: Thanks for you response @LawrenceJohnson,can you tell me which one is the easier for a beginner?

Comment: @RobertTudor - I don't want to start a big debate here about which is the best to learn first, but for someone who has no or very little backend dev experience, PHP is the easiest to get up and running with.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have a little html error.

You should change your div as below

```
<div class="row onerow"></div>
```

and your jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.onerow')
    .append('<div>new div</div>')
    addClass('abc');
});
```

And here is a demo for your case  https://jsfiddle.net/gfLajh07/

Comment: Irony...  missing `.`

Comment: Note that `$(selector).append(newhtml).addClass(..)` will add the class to the *original* selector, not to the new html.   https://jsfiddle.net/e9ynmo3w/    Using `$(newhtml).appendTo(selector).addClass(...)` will add to the newhtml

Comment: Also note that this doesn't even attempt to answer the question of how to "save" the new div over page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the attribute `class` enclosed with `"`:

```html
<div class="row onerow"></div>
```